# how to pass grails json data as directive attribute value to angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, grails, angularjs-directive

I want to pass Grails `JSON` object from Angular's custom element
directive as the attribute value to the Angular's directive. I have tries this.
But the `attrs` value are being received as a string. But I need as
`JSON` data. Whatever it may be I need to traverse as json or convert
the string to `JSON` in directive side. I have tried `angular.toJson()`, but it's not working.

**My Directive:**

```
gateApp.directive('angInputSelect',function(){
    return{
        restrict : 'E',
        controller : 'moveTaskRuleDefCtrl',
        scope : {
            dirData : '@',
        },
        replace : true,
        link : function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.taskCreateForm = attrs.dirData;
            console.log(scope.taskCreateForm);                          
        }
    }
});
```

**My Directive Template:**

```
<ang-input:select dir-data="${com.aa.fsight.MoveTaskRuleDef.MoveTaskType.class.getEnumConstants().collect{[name:it.name(), type: it.type]}}" ></ang-input:select>
```

**Executed Html gsp template:**

```
<section class="col col-3 required" label-head="Type" dir-name="moveTaskType" dir-id="moveTaskType" dir-class="select2 multiSelect selectElement" dir-model="taskCreateForm.moveTaskType" section-class="col col-3 required" dir-data="[{name=PULL, type=PULL}, {name=SPOT, type=SPOT}, {name=PULL_SPOT, type=PULL SPOT}, {name=DOCKBUMP, type=DOCKBUMP}, {name=YARD_MOVE, type=YARD MOVE}]"><label class="label ng-binding">Type</label><label class="select"><div class="select2-container select2 multiSelect selectElement" id="s2id_moveTaskType" style="width: 100%;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return false;" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">   <span class="select2-chosen"></span><abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>   <span class="select2-arrow"><b></b></span></a><input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" id="s2id_autogen15"></div><select ng-model="taskCreateForm.moveTaskType" id="moveTaskType" ng-options="moveTaskType.type as moveTaskType.name for moveTaskType in taskCreateForm" class="select2 multiSelect selectElement select2-offscreen" ng-click="calls()" tabindex="-1"><option value="?" selected="selected"></option></select></label></section>
```

**I got this data while run this in browser console:**

```
[{name=PULL, type=PULL}, {name=SPOT, type=SPOT}, {name=PULL_SPOT, type=PULL SPOT}, {name=DOCKBUMP, type=DOCKBUMP}, {name=YARD_MOVE, type=YARD MOVE}]
```

Comment: Hi, do you still get the data you mentioned above as string? If so, have you tried to use `angular.fromJson(json);`?

Comment: ya.  i have try it also..but not working..

Comment: i have try this..angular.fromJson(data); and also angular.toJson(data); and then try something unlogic var datares=angular.fromJson(data);var result=angular.toJson(datares);

Comment: So, please could you create plunker so I can test with you?

Comment: we need any encapsulation for json to traverse from .gsp page to angular directive??

Comment: actually the grails data from server side while page render..so i don't know  grails/groovy..

Comment: k can you tell me.. how to pass hot code json data as attribute data to directive..like, dir-data='[{id:'1', name:'uday'},{id:'2', name:'ravi'}]'

Comment: Hi, in your case you can use **$parse service** in your directive. here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MtGTpzQXRGLEo3IaGMVC?p=preview). Now the data variable in the directive link function is an array, so you can log something like `console.log(data[0])` and you will get the first object from the array.

Comment: dir-data="${(com.aa.fsight.MoveTaskRuleDef.MoveTaskType.class.getEnumConstants().collect{[name:it.name(), type: it.type]} as grails.converters.JSON))}"   produces... [{"name":"AAA","type":"AAA"},{"name":"BBB","type":"BBB"},{"name":"CCC","type":"CCC"}]  you may then be able to use your method above to actuall parse it since it looks like json within a map. Difference in mine and yours is that mine looks liker proper JSON, yours has key=value

Comment: i got error while run this..can anyone tell me what's this..(Error: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'name":"pull","type":"pull"},{"name":"spot","type":"spot"},{"name":"pull_spot","type":"pull' is not a valid attribute name.)

Comment: if i give static json array object means, then it  working fine.dir-data='[{id:'1', name:'uday'},{id:'2', name:'ravi'}]'..if i give grails data then it doesn't show as json string while travel..it passing as something wrong data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Groovy/Java, when you print a string you will not see the double quotes around the string. That is what is happening when you are passing it to the element directive in the view. It's not being passed as the JSON object as just the wrong formatted JSON (for javascript).

To fix this just parse it as JSON before passing it to the attribute. So modify your GSP like:

```
<ang-input:select dir-data="${new grails.converters.JSON(com.aa.fsight.MoveTaskRuleDef.MoveTaskType.class.getEnumConstants().collect{[name:it.name(), type: it.type]})}" ></ang-input:select>
```

I only wrapped your value in `new grails.converters.JSON()` constructor. Also, modify your angular code scope to use `=` instead of `@`:

```
scope : {
    dirData : '=',
},
```

Now try to log `$scope.dirData`, you should get proper list of objects.

Comment: i got this error while run this..Error: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'name":"pull","type":"pull"},{"name":"spot","type":"spot"},{"name":"pull_spot","type":"pull' is not a valid attribute name.

Comment: Can you please post the HTML code which is generated after GSP compiled.

Comment: i have update that in above edited code..see that in " Executed Html gsp template:"

Comment: ya have complete bro..thanks again..and also have one doubt..which one better for remote data typeahead box using angularjs??

Comment: I'm glad this helps! Feel free to accept the answer.

Comment: You can use the Angular's UI bootstrap library written by Angular team (if you are using Twitter Bootstrap) http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead. Otherwise, you can use another great library https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select

Comment: i got output..i made simple mistake..attribute data enclosed with " " instead of ' '..it's pbm..thanks for give support bro's